# Session timeout in spring seurity

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-security

I am new to `spring`, please help me with this problem.

I am facing a problem while using session time out in `spring security`.
when the session expires, I am redirecting my application to the login page and

I have  set that in `security.xml`, but after that login I want to navigate to the home page not the page from which the session was expired.

I just want to navigate to the home page after login page in all cases (fresh login and login due to session expire)

Please help me with the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

from spring security xsd

> **default-target-url** - The URL that will be redirected to after successful authentication...
>   **always-use-default-target** - Whether the user should always be redirected to the default-target-url after login.

you should use smth like this

```
<security:form-login
            ...
            default-target-url="/homePage"
            always-use-default-target="true"
            ... />
```